Typescript-React Arrow Function Parameter Typing
When using Typescript and passing an arrow function into another function as parameter, what would the type callout be?
My situation is with React components, and I'm trying to pass an activation function into a button component. With other such items I'll use an interface, but not sure how to type the param as being a callback function.
const activate = () => {
// Activate edit function
}

export function EditButton({ activate }): SomeInterface {

    return (
        <button className="wishButton" onClick={activate}>/</button>
    );
}


{ activate: () => void }

This question is similar to: Defining TypeScript callback type. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

// Define the type of the activate callback function
interface SomeInterface {
  activate: () => void; // This means 'activate' is a function that returns void 
}
// Define the type of the activate callback function with an argument 
interface SomeInterface {
  activate: (id: number) => void; // function that takes a number as an argument 

}

